# Spotfire unexpected result using Over with Intersect & Previous

Tags: spotfire

I'd like to create a new column with values taken from a previous row. The rows are tagged by "ID" and are ordered by "Depth" in the original table. This is the custom expression that I think should do it, but I'm getting unexpected results where some rows aren't picking up a value from the previous row.

```
Max([Value]) over Intersect([ID],Previous([Depth]))
```

Here's an example table with my expected results and the actual result given by the expression above.

```
ID      Depth   Value   Expected    Actual
Object1 0       0.02        
Object1 3033    68.87   0.02    
Object1 3349    70.82   68.87   
Object1 3538    70.65   70.82   
Object1 3791    70.38   70.65   70.65
Object1 4044    69.31   70.38   70.38
Object1 4297    71.13   69.31   69.31
Object1 4549    70.9    71.13   
Object1 4802    70.59   70.9    
Object1 5055    71.56   70.59   
Object1 5307    71.34   71.56   71.56
Object1 5560    71.32   71.34   
Object1 6381    71.5    71.32   
Object1 6444    71.62   71.5    71.5
Object1 6544    71.86   71.62   71.62
Object2 0       0.02        
Object2 962     267.58  0.02    0.02
Object2 1024    276.67  267.58  267.58
Object2 1213    273.11  276.67  276.67
Object2 1529    275.56  273.11  273.11
Object2 1593    275.96  275.56  275.56
Object2 1656    275.15  275.96  275.96
Object2 2854    278.35  275.15  275.15
Object2 3107    276.45  278.35  
Object2 3359    270.83  276.45  
Object2 4370    272.89  270.83  
Object2 4623    271.93  272.89  
Object2 4877    269.93  271.93  
Object2 5504    270.51  269.93  
Object2 5538    270.38  270.51  270.51
Object2 5541    270.37  270.38  270.38
Object2 5688    269.8   270.37
```

It seems to me that the issue might have something to do with the ordering of the Depth column. As a workaround, I can successfully get the expected result if I first calculate a rank column (call it "RankColumn")

```
Rank([Depth],[ID])
```

Then I calculate the over statement using the calculated rank

```
Max([Value]) over Intersect([ID],Previous([RankColumn]))
```

First question: why didn't Spotfire recognize the order in the original Depth column?

Second question: if conducting the intermediate rank calculation is a necessary step, is there a more elegant way to write the expression (e.g. do it in one expression rather than creating an intermediate column)?